# GWT RequestBuilder безопасно передать данные с клиента на сервер

Tags: gwt

Добрый день!

Например с сервера при запросе по адресу ".../get.php" поступает набор данных, пусть будет некий массив[1,2,3]. На клиенте по нажатию на кнопки этот массив меняется, естественно в рамках алгоритма в обработчиках. И далее при нажатии на кнопку Сохранить новый массив [4,5,6] отправляется на ".../set.php" HTTp POST запросом с параметрами=новый массив либо json'ом.

Вопрос: Возможно ли подменить данные в HTTP POST запросе или json посылаемые на сервер? Т.е. сможет какой-н зарегистрированный пользователь послать "свои" данные (например массив [10,13,1]) в ".../set.php" и как от этого защититься?

Для запросов используется RequestBuilder в GWT.

```
String url = "http://xxx.xxx/get.php";
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

    try {
      Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
           // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

          if (Response.SC_OK == response.getStatusCode()) {

              // Парсим JSON и отображаем данные клиенту

              }

              }}}

// Далее, после того как пользователь понажимал кнопки, 
// нужно отправить новый массив обратно в базу            

String url = "http://xxx.xxx/set.php";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
builder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for ( String k: parmsRequest.keySet() ) {
    String vx = URL.encodeComponent( parmsRequest.get(k));
    if ( sb.length() > 0 ) {
        sb.append("&");
    }
    sb.append(k).append("=").append(vx);
}

try {
    Request response = builder.sendRequest( sb.toString(), new RequestCallback() {

        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {}

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {}
    });
} catch (RequestException e) {}
```

Comment: Совсем не понятен твой вопрос. Если тебе надо, чтобы по пути от клиента до сервера данные не менялись, то просто используй *https*. Если же тебе надо, чтобы не все пользователи могли получать и сохранять данные, то вводи систему аутентификации и авторизации. Оба случая никак не касаются самого GWT.

Comment: Да, нужно чтобы данные могли подмениться, тем же клиентом например. Т.е. допустим мы играем в покер. Сервер мне прислал пять карт (2, 3, 5, 7, 8). Я попросил заменить 2 карты, например 2,3.  Сервер мне прислал 3, 9. Т.е сейчас у меня 3, 5, 7, 8, 9. Естественно она мне не нравится и я хочу отправить серверу свой вариант - 3,4,5,6,7. Т.е. вопрос в том могу ли я так сделать и как от этого защититься? Если я правильно понял https только шифрует данные, чтобы их не перехватили по пути. Но если сам клиент заинтересован в подмене, то как спастись от такого?

Comment: Как вариант каждый раз проверять сервером что он отправил и с тем что пришло, но насколько это правильно? не подвесит это сайт?

Comment: Защитится от такого невозможно по определению. Однако такой ситуации и возникать не должно. На стороне не клиента не должно содержаться логики, при которой он может подменить данные и сервер их примет. Как пример в онлайн играх с высокой производительностью сервер рассылает всем участникам события, далее по этим события каждая рабочая машина выстраивает модель следующей секунды. Но сервер также выстраивает эту модель и **только** эта модель является для него доверенной.